# Alinhar TextView à direita em um LinearLayout no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, layout

Olá, eu sou iniciante no Android Studio, e tive um problema com alinhamento, já dei uma olhada em perguntas similares mas não consegui resolver o problema.
Meu layout se encontra assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu preciso deixar Altitude, Latitude e Longitude à esquerda e os números, latitudeTest e longitudeTeste à direita, mais ou menos assim:


Altitude:                          10.0

Latitude:              latitudeTest

Longitude:        longitudeTest

Meu código está assim

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_horizontal_margin"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Altitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_altitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--10.0:-->
                android:text="@={``+waypoint.altitude}" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_latitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Latitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_latitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_latitude"
                android:text="latitudeTest" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lb_longitude"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                <!--Longitude:-->
                android:text="@string/lb_longitude" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/lb_longitude"
                android:text="longitudeTeste" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Agradeço sugestões e ajuda! Obrigado

Comment: Existem muitas formas de se fazer isso... Pode usar cada linha dentro de um `LinearLayout` com a orientação horizontal, pode usar `RelativeLayout`, acho que dá pra fazer com `ConstraintLayout` também... Já tentou fazer alguma dessas coisas?

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias maneiras de chega ao resultado que deseja:

**Usando apenas LinearLayout**

O jeito mais simples, seguindo a abordagem que você já começou a implementar, seria o seguinte:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

No trecho de código acima, é utilizado um LinearLayout com a [orientação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout#attr_android:orientation) vertical (para que seus itens filhos sejam dispostos um embaixo do outro), onde dentro dele são colocados X linhas, compostas por um LinearLayout com orientação na horizontal (essa orientação é a padrão, por isso não precisa declará-la), com dois TextViews dentro, cada um com o atributo [weight](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable#LinearLayout_Layout_layout_weight) = 1, que faz com que ambos os TextViews tenham o mesmo peso dentro do layout pai.

Existem outras formas, com RelativeLayout ou ConstraintLayout, mas a ideia é essa de cima.